# Why do I get an XMLHttpRequest error after trying to download a video from Firebase

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-storage

I am trying to download a video from firebase storage so that I can crop it.

But when running the code, I get an XMLHttpRequest error.

```
Error: ClientException: XMLHttpRequest error., uri=https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/aishortclipper.appspot.com/o/6wXLQCzdxDb4W1gJ4CcvDAy52MH3%2F1%2FUntitled.mov?alt=media&token=29c5cdbc-0f00-435a-9110-5286e5cd889b
    dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/patch/core_patch.dart 941:28                get current
packages/http/src/browser_client.dart 81:22                                       <fn>
dart-sdk/lib/async/zone.dart 1661:54                                              runUnary
dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 156:18                                        handleValue
dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 840:44                                        handleValueCallback
dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 869:13                                        _propagateToListeners
dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 632:7                                         [_complete]
dart-sdk/lib/async/stream_pipe.dart 61:11                                         _cancelAndValue
dart-sdk/lib/async/stream.dart 1581:7                                             <fn>
dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/private/ddc_runtime/operations.dart 574:37  _checkAndCall
dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/private/ddc_runtime/operations.dart 579:39  dcall
dart-sdk/lib/html/dart2js/html_dart2js.dart 37263:58                              <fn>


dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/private/ddc_runtime/errors.dart 327:10  createErrorWithStack
dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/patch/core_patch.dart 337:28            _throw
dart-sdk/lib/core/errors.dart 120:5                                           throwWithStackTrace
dart-sdk/lib/async/zone.dart 1386:11                                          callback
dart-sdk/lib/async/schedule_microtask.dart 40:11                              _microtaskLoop
dart-sdk/lib/async/schedule_microtask.dart 49:5                               _startMicrotaskLoop
dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/patch/async_patch.dart 181:15           <fn>
```

The code:

```
onTap: () async{
    final response = await http.get(Uri.parse("https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/aishortclipper.appspot.com/o/6wXLQCzdxDb4W1gJ4CcvDAy52MH3%2F1%2FUntitled.mov?alt=media&token=29c5cdbc-0f00-435a-9110-5286e5cd889b"));
    final docDir = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    final file = File(path.join(docDir.path, "cropVideo.mp4"));
    file.writeAsBytesSync(response.bodyBytes);
    Navigator.of(context).push(
        MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (context) => Crop(file: file)
        )
    );
},
```

I set the read-and-write rules to true but the issue still remains

Comment: "I get an XMLHttpRequest error" Please edit your question to include the exact error message and complete stacktrace of the error.

Comment: If you paste that URL into Postman and inspect the response headers, you'll see that there are no CORS headers. Your browser therefore refuses to connect (unless you were to host your Flutter web application at the same server). See https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/download-files for how to add CORS headers.

Comment: @RichardHeap the link you showed is for web, is it the same for flutter?

Comment: You'd only be using XMLHttpRequest if you are using Flutter Web.